# how to get css element at parent document from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have `<div id='footer'>`at parent document, and doesn't have CSS attribute on it.
After loading the document, I would like to know the CSS attribute from that element from the iframe. I would like to know the top properties, and left width height will follows.

I use this, but not working.

```
footer=$('#footer', window.parent.document);
footer=$(footer);
alert(footer.top);
```

It says 'undefined' at alert dialog

Comment: Why are you wrapping a jquery object in a jquery wrapper? The second line should not be there. Also if you want css use .css("top")

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
footer=$('#footer', window.parent.document);
alert(footer.position().top);
```

Read [position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/)

Or use [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) like,

```
alert(footer.css('top'));
```